# angular2 -set up getting error as `Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined`

Tags: angular, systemjs

I am trying to setup the `angular2` app with my local system. without using any `feeds`. but i am getting error as `Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined` - but `systemjs` folder is there, is there in my moulde folder.

what is wrong with my set-up here?

here is my html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>A2-App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/global.css">
</head>
<body>
    <hello-app>Loading...</hello-app>
</body>
<!-- ES6-related imports -->
<script src="js/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="js/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="js/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>//file exist there, but getting 404
<script>
    //configure system loader
    System.config({defaultJSExtensions: true});
</script>
<script src="js/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="js/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //bootstrap the Angular2 application
    System.import('dist/app').catch(console.log.bind(console));
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you move all your scripts in the head and move System.config / System.import after Importing js files?

Comment: done, still no luck. I am using `sublime` it is giving autofil to all `lib` files other than `systemjs` - this is for your additional info

Comment: On which line does the error occurs? Within your HTML file?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier - line number 19 `System.config({defaultJSExtensions: true});`

Comment: Thanks! Could you make a try with SystemJS provided by code.angularjs.org/tools? Your configuration should work...

Comment: @ThierryTemplier, yes this is working. then what is the issue with my code? I installed my system.js using `npm`

Comment: Which versions of angular2 and systemjs do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem comes from the version of SystemJS you use. Here are the versions:

- angular2 beta9
- systemjs 0.19.24

And include it this way:

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

See this page for more details:

- https://angular.io/guide/quickstart